# Laravel having trouble sending decimals

Tags: laravel, decimal, laravel-blade

I have a blade template form that takes a price

```
              {!!Form::open(array('method'=>'POST','route'=>array('order.store'))) !!}

              <div class="form-group">

                {!! Form::label('price', 'Price:', ['class' => 'control-label']) !!}
                {!! Form::number('price', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
               </div>


               {!! Form::submit('Submit Order', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) !!}
                {!! Form::close() !!}
```

The controller takes price and send it to email:

```
class OrderController extends Controller
{
 public function store()
    {
            $data=Input::all();
            //Validation rules
            $rules = array (


              'price'       => 'required|regex:/[\d]{2}.[\d]{2}/',
             );

     $validator  = Validator::make ($data, $rules);


             //If everything is correct than run passes.
        if ($validator -> passes()){

            //Send email using Laravel send function
            Mail::send('emails.order_received', $data, function($msg) use ($data)
            {
            //email 'From' field: Get users email add and name
                $msg->from($data['email'] , $data['owner']);
            //email 'To' field: change this to emails that you want to be notified.                    
                $msg->to('on@dx.com', 'Rn')->subject('New Order');

            });

            return Redirect::route('order.index')->with('flash_notice', 'Thank you');  
         }

        else
        {
            //return contact form with errors

            return Redirect::route('order.index')->withErrors($validator)->with('flash_error', 'This is not how one shops');
        }
    }
  }
```

The table is passed to a email template.

```
    <?php
//get the first name
$item = Input::get('item');
$manufacturer = Input::get ('manufacturer');
$price = Input::get('price');
$quantity = Input::get ('quantity');
$product_code = Input::get ('product_code');
$owner = Input::get ('owner');
$email = Input::get("email");
$created_at = Input::get("date");
?>
```

When ever I try to add a price i.e. (3.65) the blade form continues to return an error message for an integer. My migration takes price as a decimal(2,2) I can't understand why my form is throwing errors. Any help would be much appreciated.

P.S. Other than the regex rule I have tried float and decimal. Now if I try entering 2 instead of 02.00 with the regex rule it throws an error based on the regex. However if I try adhering to the regex rule it wants an integer (error says between X and Y).

Thanks
M

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you'll definitely want to use the `numeric` rule for your validation.

Secondly, you are using the HTML5 input field `number` which by default only accepts integers, not floats.

If you want it to also accept floats and therefore not trigger the browser built in validation change your code to the following:

```
{!! Form::number('price', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'step' => 'any']) !!}
```

Or, of course, you could just use an `text` input and do the inline validation yourself.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply Tim! When i try to validate with float I receive a Method [validateFloat] does not exist error. I am using Laravel 5 btw.

Comment: I'm sorry, my bad. The validation rule I had in mind is named `numeric` in Laravel.